# Apply different data augmentation to part of the train set based on the category

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, data-augmentation

I'm working on a machine learning process to classify images. My problem is that my dataset is imbalanced, and in my 5 categories of images, I have about 400 images in of one class, and about 20 images of each of the other classes.

I would like to balance my train set by applying data augmentation only to certain classes of my train set.

Here's the code I'm using for creating the train an validation sets:

```
# Import data
data_dir = pathlib.Path(r"C:\Train set")

# Define train and validation sets (80% - 20%)
batch_size = 32
img_height = 240
img_width = 240

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

And here's how I apply data augmentation, although this would be for the entire train set:

```
# Apply data augmentation
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
  [
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal", 
                                                 input_shape=(img_height, 
                                                              img_width,
                                                              3)),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.1),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.1),
  ]
)
```

Is there any way to go into my train set, extract those categories that have fewer images, and apply data augmentation only to them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest not using `ImageDataGenerator` but a customized `tf.data.Dataset`. In a mapping operation, you can treat categories differently, e.g.:

```
def preprocess(filepath):
    category = tf.strings.split(filepath, os.sep)[0]
    read_file = tf.io.read_file(filepath)
    decode = tf.image.decode_jpeg(read_file, channels=3)
    resize = tf.image.resize(decode, (200, 200))
    image = tf.expand_dims(resize, 0)
    if tf.equal(category, 'tf_astronauts'):
        image = tf.image.flip_up_down(image)
        image = tf.image.flip_left_right(image)
    # image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    # category = tf.cast(tf.equal(category, 'tf_astronauts'), tf.int32)
    return image, category
```

Let me demonstrate it. Let's make you a folder with training images:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from skimage import data
from glob2 import glob
import os

cat = data.chelsea()
astronaut = data.astronaut()

for category, picture in zip(['tf_cats', 'tf_astronauts'], [cat, astronaut]):
    os.makedirs(category, exist_ok=True)
    for i in range(5):
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(category, category + f'_{i}.jpg'),
                    cv2.cvtColor(picture, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))

files = glob('tf_*\\*.jpg')
```

Now you have these files:

```
['tf_astronauts\\tf_astronauts_0.jpg',
 'tf_astronauts\\tf_astronauts_1.jpg',
 'tf_astronauts\\tf_astronauts_2.jpg',
 'tf_astronauts\\tf_astronauts_3.jpg',
 'tf_astronauts\\tf_astronauts_4.jpg',
 'tf_cats\\tf_cats_0.jpg',
 'tf_cats\\tf_cats_1.jpg',
 'tf_cats\\tf_cats_2.jpg',
 'tf_cats\\tf_cats_3.jpg',
 'tf_cats\\tf_cats_4.jpg']
```

Let's apply tranformations only to the astronaut category. Let's use the `tf.image` transformations.

```
def preprocess(filepath):
    category = tf.strings.split(filepath, os.sep)[0]
    read_file = tf.io.read_file(filepath)
    decode = tf.image.decode_jpeg(read_file, channels=3)
    resize = tf.image.resize(decode, (200, 200))
    image = tf.expand_dims(resize, 0)
    if tf.equal(category, 'tf_astronauts'):
        image = tf.image.flip_up_down(image)
        image = tf.image.flip_left_right(image)
    # image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
    # category = tf.cast(tf.equal(category, 'tf_astronauts'), tf.int32)
    return image, category
```

Then, we make the `tf.data.Dataset`:

```
train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files).\
    shuffle(10).take(4).map(preprocess).batch(4)
```

And when you iterate the dataset, you'll see that only the astronaut is flipped:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.1, hspace=.2)
images, labels = next(iter(train))
for index, (image, label) in enumerate(zip(images, labels)):
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 2, index + 1)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_title(label.numpy().decode())
    ax.imshow(image[0].numpy().astype(int))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Please note, for training you will need to uncomment the two lines in `preprocess` so it returns an array of floats and an integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'mt not quite how to apply the preprocess function though... Is the filepath the path to the directory of each of my image categories?

Comment: The filename to the image yes

Comment: The preprocessing function is just passed as the callable in `tf.data.Dataset.map()`, that's how it should be used.

Comment: if you store augmentations in a preprocessing step, augmentations will be treated as individual samples - wont that inflate your metric and artificially lower the loss? Compared to only letting the network see the same source in an augmented form once per epoch, as would be the case with augmentation on the fly.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: is it possible to increase the dataset that way in size (not only diversity). So that each time we augment, we also create a copy of the image that is also added to the dataset? 
So basically, can I oversample a minority class with augmented images that way?